Replace generates "Run-time error 13: Type mismatch" when Range contains more than 1 cell
I'm trying to apply Replace to a range of cells.
It gives me

Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

Sub RemovePrefix()
    Dim Str As String

    Str = Sheets("Input").Range("C3:J3")
    Str = Replace(Str, "Username / Nama TikTok : ", "")
    Sheets("Input").Range("C3:J3") = Str
    
End Sub



Str is VBA built-in function. Pls don't use it as a variable.
Sheets("Input").Range("C3:J3") returns a 2D array. Replace function doesn't work with it.

Sub RemovePrefix()
    Dim aData, i As Long
    With Sheets("Input").Range("C3:J3")
        aData = .Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
            aData(1, i) = Replace(aData(1, i), "Username / Nama TikTok : ", "")
        Next
        .Value = aData
    End With
End Sub

OR
Sub ReplaceAll()

    Sheets("Input").Range("C3:J3").Replace What:="Username / Nama TikTok : ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        
End Sub

